# How to use Javascript and show result for a new Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to use javascript in Ruby on Rails framework, but it does not show any effect.

I made a html file connect with javascript. It works by double-clicking the html file and can see the javascript result.

But when I tried to put them into Ruby on Rails. I have no idea where shall I put the javascript in.

I created a new rails app with controller pages and views/pages/home.html.erb and assets/javascripts/pages.coffee.
I put the html code into the pages/home.html.erb but where shall I put the javascript in- javascripts/application.js or javascripts/pages.coffee or created a new xx.js file? How to make it work? I tried to put the js code in the above, but it does not work at all. [![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2][![enter image description here][3]][3]

---

Pre-work I have done but not had any effect
1. Ruby on Rails-4.2
2. Have added the two gems
   - gem 'execjs'
   - gem 'therubyracer'
3. Assets/javascripts/application.js
   - require jquery
   - require jquery_ujs
   - require turbolinks
   - require_tree .
4. Installed processingjs
   - gem install processingjs
5. Installed node.js

```js
require jquery
require jquery_ujs
require turbolinks
require_tree .

var jsMain = function(processingInstance){ with (processingInstance){
size(400, 400);  // set size of canvas

// add your code here ...
background(255, 0, 0);

}};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Playproject</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Playproject 2</h1>

<h1>
<canvas id="pageCanvas"></canvas>
</h1>

<p align="center">
 <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</p>

</body>

<script src="../processing-1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/javascripts/application.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, jsMain);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is put javascript in html for the present. But I think you may put javascript code in `assets/javascript/pages.coffee`.

You need use `app/views/layouts/appliaction.html.erb` because `application.js` need compile.

How about this?

```
$ rails g controller pages
```

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
get 'pages/home' => 'pages#home'
```

`appliation.js` not changed.

download`processing.js` and put `app/assets/javasctipts/`

http://processingjs.org/

app/views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<h1>Playproject 2</h1>

<h1>
<canvas id="pageCanvas">canvas</canvas>
</h1>

<p align="center">
    <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</p>

</body>

<script type="application/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

var jsMain = function(processingInstance){ with (processingInstance){
  size(400, 400);
  background(255, 0, 0);
}};

var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, jsMain);

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Atsushi! It really helps. Can I have a couple of questions, I want to create a header which can change the size of header when I scroll down. I followed this instruction, but cannot make the javascript work on rails.  http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll                       Thanks again and appreciate.

Comment: It is a similar question as above, I think I do not understand how javascript is compiled in the rails structure? As above, I put all the processing js code in the application, it works, can I have another way, put those processing code in a file 'processing.js' under assets/js/processing.js, then use it in the html? Thanks again and appreciate!!